How to encrypt a message sent to a SignalR group backed by Azure SignalR Services
The following C# code calls an HTTP-triggered Azure Function with "negotiate" endpoint to conduct SignalR negotiation:
var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:7071", options =>
                {
                    options.Headers.Add("x-ms-signalr-userid", SystemUserId!);
                    options.Headers.Add("x-functions-key", ConnectionParameters!.SecretKey!);
                })
                .WithAutomaticReconnect([TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5)])
                .Build();

After a successful negotiation, the client gets connected to the SignalR hub and therefore OnConnected event or "Upstream" is triggered to call back an SignalR-triggered Azure function. One of the steps that this SignalR-triggered function does is to add the user to the group of users by instantiating and reporting/returning SignalRGroupAction object found in Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker namespace. Therefore, any messages sent to the group can easily be sent out by calling another Azure SignalR-triggered or even HTTP-triggered function and have the function return an instance of SingalRMessageAction. Example:
 [Function("SendMessageToGroup")]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "MyHub")]
    public SignalRMessageAction SendMessageToGroup([SignalRTrigger("MyHub", "Category", "msgSent", "username", "message")] SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext, string username, string message)
    {
        return new SignalRMessageAction() { Arguments = [message], GroupName = "MyGroup" }
    }

The challenge I am experiencing is the message could be a plain text visible to the Azure function app and it could imply the breach of privacy. What is the best way to encrypt messages sent to a group such that the recipients (the group's users) can only decrypt and read it.

You can use  System.Security.Cryptography namespace and its functionality?

@RithwikBojja I know such a library exists but that must happen in the client side. How do you track the encryption keys in the group?
